# Web site thumbnails for the Windows 8 Share Charm

Tags: html, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, charms-bar

According to [Link Previews (Windows) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thumb_image_tags), a website can set an image or thumbnail to represent itself in the Share Charm on Windows 8. This is achieved by including one of four `meta` elements with an image.

I have tried using this, but cannot see that this information is used for anything. I don't see the thumbnail I set being applied anywhere related to the Share action.

Does anyone know anything about where this information is used?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you share it. For example if you email it, it will show the thumbnail image next to the description in the body of the mail.

Comment: I can’t get that to work at all. Have tried different tags, image formats, and sizes. An image never shows up in the mail pane.